# Finder "Open With" very slow

Tags: macos, finder

I have the latest version of OS Yosemite (10.10.5) on a very powerful MBP (i7, 2.4, 16GB RAM).

When I right-click on a file in Finder and choose "Open with", "Other", the dialog window is very unresponsive:

- it takes time (minutes) to populate the /Applications folder.
- Scrolling the content of the /Applications folder is incredibly slow, the content takes seconds to move when I scroll the mouse wheel and I spend not less than a minute trying to reach the correct application I want to use.
- When I finally reach the correct application and click on it, it takes 1-2 seconds to highlight the item I selected and another couple of seconds to enable the "OK" button.

This happens every time I select "Open with - Other" and not only the first time.

Is there anyone who can suggest a solution for this problem, it is incredibly annoying. I have never experienced such a weird behaviour on any OS X version.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I tried rebuilding the Launch Services Database to no avail. I also notice that the slowdown coincides with a task called videosubscriptionsd taking up 80%+ cpu. I followed some other problems with said daemon but found the videosubscriptionsd sqlite database to be entirely empty.

Answer (score 6):

Try rebuilding the Launch Services database, which populates the Open With menu. It can sometimes get corrupted, which can cause duplicate entries, slowdowns and other weirdness.

If you're comfortable with the Terminal, you can do this with a single command:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user
```

Otherwise, a free GUI tool like [Onyx](http://www.titanium.free.fr) can do it at the push of a button.

Comment: scottishwildcat is correct but if you are not comfortable with the command line Onyx is the way to go. In fact I use Onyx 2-3 times a year to clean up the Mac and force it to do any built in maintenance scripts it might have (somehow) missed.

Comment: Is this still legit for macOS Sierra and High Sierra?

Comment: Yes. You can find more detail on the commands (and some alternative ones you might try) here: https://eclecticlight.co/2017/08/11/launch-services-database-problems-correcting-and-rebuilding/

Comment: it works when you run the command but in my case it slowed down again after a while